# Reading two text files and copying text from one file to other given satisfied condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two text files, A.txt and B.txt.
Each line in A.txt is of the following form:

```
[Num]WordA1 WordA2 WordA3
```

Each line in B.txt is of the following form:

```
WordB1 WordB2 [Num] WordB3 WordB4
```

The idea is I want to find the lines in A.txt that contain the same [Num] as some line in B.txt and add the string in the fourth column of that line in B.txt to the second column of the associated line in A.txt. For example, say A.txt contains

```
[32]Apple Banana Orange
[73]Kiwi Grape Lemon
```

And B.txt contains

```
Blue Red [32] Green Black
Red White [105] Purple Green
Brown Pink [73] Blue Black
```

I would want the output (so, in A.txt) to be:

```
[32]Apple Green Banana Orange
[73]Kiwi Blue Grape Lemon
```

So to generalize, how do I match lines across two text files based on a string in a specified position and add another string in one of the matched lines to the other line, in a specified position?

Comment: you are probably going to need to use regular expression to fine the values inside if `[ ]` and then use that to match your numbers. Once you have match a number you can then output that line to the console or to a GUI widget.

Comment: How big is B.txt? If it's not too large, you could load its data into a dict with the number as the key and the 4th column string as the value. Then you can just loop over the old A.txt line by line.

Comment: B.txt is about a thousand lines long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do this with regular expression.

First we open each file.

Then we compare the values of each row inside of the `[]` brackets.

Once we find a match we can print each line.

```
import re

file_a = open("./A.txt", "r")

file_b = open("./B.txt", "r")

for a_line in file_a:
    a = re.findall(r"([0-9]+)", a_line)

    for b_line in file_b:
        b = re.findall(r"([0-9]+)", b_line)
        if a == b:
            print(a_line)
            print(b_line)

    file_b.seek(0)

file_a.close()
file_b.close()
```

The results with the date you gave as an example look like this:

```
[32]Apple Banana Orange

Blue Red [32] Green Black

[73]Kiwi Grape Lemon
Brown Pink [73] Blue Black
```

Comment: Why is this importing `tkinter`?

Comment: @ScottHunter: Force of habit. I answer a lot of tkinter question. Removing now.

Comment: The file iterator will be exhausted when the inner for loop runs for the second time. You could run `file_b.seek(0)`.

Comment: @anonymoose: My mistake. thank you for that. I have corrected my code.